# Auto PEP8 Alias

Tags: bash

```
alias pep='find . -name '*.py' -exec autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive '{}' \;
```

I am using [autopep8](https://atom.io/packages/python-autopep8)

When I run this command manually on the terminal the executions is good and the autopep8 works, but when I am trying to execute as an alias this is the error I get:

```
find: cli.py: unknown primary or operator
```

Comment: You can't nest single quotes, `'foo'bar'baz'` is an unquoted `bar` between quoted strings `'foo'` and `'baz'`. Don't use aliases anyway; a function solves this elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quoting issues -- use single quotes around the whole string and double quotes around all other places inside:

```
alias pep='find . -name "*.py" -exec autopep8 --in-place \
             --aggressive --aggressive "{}" \;'
```

Also, quoting around empty `{}` is not strictly necessary:

```
alias pep='find . -name "*.py" -exec autopep8 --in-place \
             --aggressive --aggressive {} \;'
```